# Writing certain functions as power series without using Taylor series

Tags: power-series

How would one expand the following functions as power series around the given points:

- $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ around $2$
- $g(x) = \frac{x}{x-3}$ around $5$

I know how to do that using Taylor series. Is there another method?

Comment: If a function can be written as a power series $\sum_{n\geqslant 0} a_n x^n$, then the coefficients $a_n$ are uniquely determined... so they are necessarily equal to $f^{(n)}(0)/n!$.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83951/uniqueness-of-power-series

Comment: Yes, @LukeCollins, but one still has to show that the Taylor series converges to the function

Comment: The hint is: geometric series.

Comment: I see! Would estimating the error of the Taylor polynomials using the Lagrange remainder work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, write $1/x=1/(2+x-2)$ and divide by $2$ getting:

$(1/2)/1-((2-x)/2)$ . Clearly $(2-x)/2$ < $1$ in a neighborhood of $2$

hence $1/(1-((2-x)/2)=1+(2-x)/2+((2-x)/2)^{2}+((2-x)/2)^{3}+.....$ and

multiplying by $1/2$ we get the expansion.

In the second case we write $1/((x-5)+2)$ and dividing by $2$ we

obtain $(1/2)(1/((x-5)/2)+1$ which is

$(1/2)(1-((x-5)/2)+((x-5)/2)^{2}-((x-5)/2)^{3}+......)$.

Multiplying this expansion by $x$ which can be written as $(x-5)+5$ we get the required expansion!